# Avada theme, Wordpress, Header Logo Customization,

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, themes, customization

i'm having an issue with WordPress Avada theme i'm not managing to solve myself.
I need to have the logo in the menu like this:

```
body #header-sticky .logo, #header .logo {
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

but something override it to:

```
element.style {
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 31px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 31px;
}
```

and i don't see what is it in my style.css

I can't find where to modify the final HTML file the theme produces, does anyone knows how to achieve this?

[NinjaMate.com](http://ninjamate.com)

Comment: It is inline css....go to header.php and change the inline css in theme folder

Comment: @TamilSelvan what should I look for there? I didn't find margin logo, 31 and so on...

Comment: Then use !important in css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use !important

```
body #header-sticky .logo, #header .logo {
  margin-right: 0px !important;
  margin-top: 20px !important;
  margin-left: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: 16px !important;
}
```

or use shorthand css

```
body #header-sticky .logo, #header .logo { 
  margin: 20px 0px 16px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Work now. It affected my @media css but I think that I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your backend go to **Appearance** > **Theme Options** > **Logo**, there you will find all the options related to your logo (including the margin)